# OneToMany mapping with JoinTable doesn't show up in the database

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I would like to model a 1:n relationship between the Player and Hero class. To make it clear: A player should have multiple heroes whilst a hero only belongs to a single player.

The relevant excerpt (getters, setters and irrelevant properties stripped) of my player class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "player_id", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Table(name = "players")
public class Player {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "players_heroes", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "player_id") }, 
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "hero_id") })
    private Set<Hero> mHeroes;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "player_id", nullable = false)
    private Long mId;
}
```

The hero class looks quite similar and currently lacks any possibility to retrieve the owning player as even the basic assocation doesn't work yet:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "hero_id", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Table(name = "heros")
public class Hero {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "hero_id", nullable = false)
    private Long mId;
}
```

I am currently generating the database schema by using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create` and what it gives me is the following output:

```
Hibernate: create table heros (hero_id int8 not null, [...] primary key (hero_id))
Hibernate: create table players (player_id int8 not null, [...], primary key (player_id))
```

The associaton is clearly missing :( Can anybody see something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need the join table for anything else?  Join tables are typically used for many to many associations.

Comment: I need to enumerate all heroes belonging to a player in a efficient way. Somehow I assumed this would be faster using a join table instead of a join column, but thats wrong as I have just recognized. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just a dumb mistake not visible in the snippets I have given: A runaway comment.

Comment: You should consider closing the question, since there is nothing helpful in it for further readers.